# How to return to same activity and keep the content after back from Home clicking

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc

Please help with an issue I'm facing.

First, I know, normally, when we open an app, navigate to some activity, click Home Button, and then return back to the app, we'll return to the last activity with all content saved.

But it's a little bit different in my app. There are 4 activities in my app. 'LoginActivity' is the main activity. When we click app icon, it will be triggered. And it will automatically start 'MainActivity' if user saved his/her login (using SharedPreferences). User can also launch the app by tapping the phone to NFC tag and 'NFCTagTriggeredActivity' will be triggered.

Now the issue is, if I launch the app by tapping the phone to an NFC tag, i.e. through 'NFCTagTriggeredActivity', click Home Button then go back to the app again, it cannot go back to 'NFCTagTriggeredActivity' anymore. Instead, it will go back to 'MainActivity'. Similarly, if I launch the app by tapping an NFC tag and navigate to 'OtherActivity', click Home Button then go back. It will go back to 'MainActivity'

I suspect this has something to do with intent-filter setting, but cannot figure out how to solve this issue. Attached the AndroidManifest.xml and part of Java code. Please let me know if any further info needed.

Any help is appreciated!

```
   <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NFCTagTriggeredActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nfc_tag_triggered"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="test/nfc"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OtherActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_other"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);

    if (sharedPrefs.getInt(Configs.USER_ID, 0) != 0 && sharedPrefs.getBoolean(Configs.LOGIN_STATUS, false)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.myapp",
                "com.myapp.MainActivity");
        this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

NFCTagTriggeredActivity

```
public class NFCTagTriggeredActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NFCTagTriggeredActivity.this);

       if (sharedPrefs.getInt(Configs.USER_ID, 0) == 0 || !sharedPrefs.getBoolean(Configs.LOGIN_STATUS, false)) {
           Toast.makeText(NFCTagTriggeredActivity.this, "Please log in or sign up first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setClassName("com.myapp",
                "com.myapp.LoginActivity");
           this.startActivity(intent);
           finish();
       }

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc_tag_triggered);

       Intent mIntent = this.getIntent();

       Parcelable[] parcelables = mIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

       tag = this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

       //...

   }
}
```

Comment: So, why not use fragments ? basically is an activity which runs different smaller activities( Very simplistically ). It sounds that if you use fragments the application could be done in less effort. I don't want to post it as a solution but if it is a solution let me know to post it later and you can upvote it.

Comment: @giorgos1993 Thanks for comment. Actually these 4 activities are quite different. I guess I cannot use fragments here. I just post part of the related Java code, so they might seem the same:)